# CRM 2011 System Workflow Sends Email Which Contains Link

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, html-email, email-client, workflow-activity

I am sending email activity using system Workflow. It sends email where email-body contains a link.

What I do that I insert a link using "Hyperlink" button on the Email-Template provided by the System Workflow.

When this email received at on Outlook it works fine. If it is received on Thunderbird or Gmail or Yahoo, it distracted.

That "Link" text does not works as link anymore and it's value(i.e full URL) displayed over there.

What i can do for this in email template to works on other EMail client.

I formulate this email using system Workflow. I don't have such flexibility over here.

Any idea will be appreciated. Please help.

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: Please double check your Hyperlink. I have notice recently, when you save the template, sometimes CRM automatically put some unwanted chevrons  ('>', '<').

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have also faced the same. but then i double check before activating the system WF in that case.

If this special character will remain then it will reflect in email as well.

so basically you are saying that this special character should be present or not?

Comment: Is this hyperlink that you are sending static or dynamic? Is it pointing back to a CRM record or a link outside CRM?

Comment: That is dynamics URL i.e value of one url-field in entity record.
It is fine now..:)

The problem was about alignment, formatting and thsi is the reason URL expanded in 2-3 line and due to some spaces it distracted.

I found a solution and copy-pasted the HTML from browser to the email Template and then replacing the dynamics values.

Now It's working f9..:)